# Standard way to take backup of mysql running inside Kubernetes pod?

Tags: database, kubernetes

i am having Kubernetes cluster on digital ocean and running database inside k8s pod.

I am planning for schedule backup eveyday so what is best way for everyday auto backup. JOB or JENKINS ?

> Database is not exposed outside using any service

if i use K8s job how to store backup in PVC and how to delete old one?

I am already running script to take snapshot of volume via jenkin is good way to restore?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41014085/backup-recover-kubernetes-current-state-namespaces-pods-controllers-etc, https://medium.com/@pmvk/kubernetes-backups-and-recovery-efc33180e89d

Comment: @sulabhchaturvedi thankyou for reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can consider one of the below approach

1. Create a CronJob in k8s and run backup using mysql service dns.
2. install cron inside mysql container ( update mysql image with cron) and run mysql backup at scheduled interval. archive the backup and push it to s3 storage.

Comment: can't i run JOB in k8s ?

Comment: you can. but you might want to run backup at regular intervals. so cron is preferred

Comment: i think i can also setup cron in K8s job

Comment: or i can use jenkins run schedule snapshot of volume

Comment: in the first point above, i was referring to run CronJob in kubernetes

Comment: ohhh ok thankyou so much reply ...so as per your suggestion cronjob take backup anad upload it to s3?

Comment: you need to develop a shell script to run mysqldump and tar it and push it to s2 storage. run the shell script from the container that you are going to use in CronJob pod

Comment: Thankyou so much for reply got it